# Why does git not fetch the pull request I merged in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I'm having some git trouble. My setup is as follows:

[workstation repo] -origin-> [network drive bare repo] -origin-> [GitHub]

I just accepted my first pull request on GitHub ([this one](https://github.com/Captain-Chaos/WorldPainter/pull/100)) and merged it to master. Now I want to pull it to my workstation. So I do `git fetch` on the network drive, and then `git pull` on my workstation, but on my workstation git says 'Already up-to-date' and refuses to merge the change (I checked, it's not in my workspace).

The output of `git branch -vv` on the network drive includes the line:

```
* master                    0fe40e2 [origin/master: behind 2] Some small code improvements
```

The output of `git branch -vv` on the workstation repo includes the line:

```
* master         0fe40e2 [origin/master] Some small code improvements
```

The actual commit they should be pointing to is [3388641](https://github.com/Captain-Chaos/WorldPainter/commit/338864196d59b86d3b42c4fffc88f56aecb75433). It looks like in the bare repo on the network drive the master branch is somehow behind origin/master. I have no idea how this situation arose, or how to fix it. I can't use `git pull` or `git reset` since it is a bare repo.

Does anyone know how I can determine what the problem is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the purpose of this separate bare clone is (the bare clone being the one you say is on a network drive), but if it's not a *mirror* clone—mirrors being a particular type of bare clone—it has its own branch names, independent of all other Git repositories.<sup>1</sup>  Therefore, you'll need to tell it to *update* any particular branch if and when you want it to slave itself to some other Git repository.

> I can't use `git pull` or `git reset` since it is a bare repo ...

It is true that you cannot use `git pull`, because it is a bare repository and `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command* and that second Git command is always one that needs a work-tree.  However, it's *not* the case that you cannot use `git reset`.  What you cannot do is do a mixed or hard reset:

```
$ git reset
fatal: mixed reset is not allowed in a bare repository
$ git reset --hard
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
```

A `--soft` reset is, however, allowed:

```
$ git reset --soft
$
```

so one way to move the local `master` to match `origin/master` is:

```
$ git reset --soft origin/master
```

However, the most appropriate thing is probably to either stop using this bare repository entirely, or use a mirror clone (see footnote 1).

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, even a mirror clone has its own branch names.  The key difference between a non-mirror bare clone and a mirror bare clone is that the mirror clone has all of its branch names slaved to its origin.<sup>2</sup>  Specifically, the `fetch` configuration for a mirror clone is:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

rather than the standard:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The standard fetch setting means that `git fetch` run in such a clone updates all the `refs/remotes/origin/*` names to match origin's `refs/heads/*` names.  The nonstandard mirror setting means that `git fetch` run in a mirror clone forcibly updates all of the `refs/heads/*` names, immediately forgetting (and thereby losing any commits solely reachable from) its own branch names in favor of using the fetched names instead.  That's what makes the mirror a mirror: it drops any commits that *were* exclusive to its own branches by replacing its own branch name commit hashes with whatever it saw on the remote.

<sup>2</sup>The description above assumes the standard remote name `origin`.  If you used some other name, everything still holds, it's just that instead of `origin`, the string literal is whatever name you used.

Comment: Interesting. This would seem to suggest that this would have never worked, and I just never noticed because this is the first time I'm actually fetching something *from* GitHub.

The bare repo exists as local backup and centralised repository for working on the code from different locations. It is not a mirror clone; I'll investigate turning it into one. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, the `git reset --soft` worked! I found a page describing how turn the bare repo into a mirror repo, which I have done. I haven't tested that yet, but I trust that it will work. Thank you very much!